# why java code coverage still show yellow color when enable assertions

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing

[image]

I run code coverage for the code in eclipse by setting the jvm paramter : -ea,  but the statements still show yellow color. and test2 show red, why?

what's more,  when I use -ea, if the system assertions(-esa) be enable? It seems that when I use -esa, -ea can't work.

Comment: If you are using [eclemma](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/annotations.html), this is for party covered lines.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You were trying to run code coverage after enabling assertions.

Comment: I know it is be party coveraged, but "boolean b=key!=null" should be fully covered. isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never ran it with a null key value, and hence the assertion path was never exercised.

(This point came to me because I ran into the identical problem in about 1980.)

Comment: can you explain it in detail?

Comment: I modify the test and add null as parameter, but it isn't work too

Comment: Dynamic code coverage tools work by monitoring execution of the underlying machine instructions while the program runs. Basically they have a table of 1 bit per instruction and set the bit if the instruction is executed.  The `assert` compiles into a test and branch around a call to the assertion failure routine.  The call never gets executed unless you force an assertion failure.  But likely there's another instruction or 3 on the return path from the routine that won't ever be executed, so you can never get 100%.  (For similar reasons `boolean b=key!=null` wasn't covered.)

Answer (score -2):

I get the answer:

0x9a    ifne    当栈顶int型数值不等于0时跳转。

0x2b

aload_1
将第二个引用类型局部变量推送至栈顶。

0x59    dup     复制栈顶数值并将复制值压入栈顶。 
0xbf    athrow  将栈顶的异常抛出。

0xb1    return  从当前方法返回void。 
0xb2    getstatic   获取指定类的静态域，并将其值压入栈顶。

0xb6    invokevirtual   调用实例方法。

only enable assert or disable it at one time. so can't cover all branches.